# How to do a whole word search in a tab separated array

Tags: livecode

I have an array that looks like the list below.

I need to find the id of a color by finding which line it appears in and the first item of that line is the id for the color.

I tried the following code but it is not working because I believe it is search for the whole word in the entire line. How do I change the code so that the lineoffset onlt apply to the second item of each line?

```
set the wholeMatches to true
put lineOffset("red",colors) into theLine
```

1   blue

2   pink

3   reddish orange

4   orange

5   green

6   red

7   black

8   yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the filter command.

```
filter lines of gArrSymptoms with "*" & tab & theSymptom & "*" into temp
put word 1 of temp into theIndex
```

Where "theSympton" is the symptom you are looking up and "theIndex" is the number you want.

The * is a wildcard to catch the start and end of the line.

The "tab" is required to ensure secondary components are not picked ahead of primary ones.
e.g. "Diarrhea" is included twice as a secondary term as well as once as a primary one.

Which makes me wonder how you ensure a correct term is selected in the first place.

If your array was in a list field then the following script for that field would also give you the index wanted..

```
on mouseup
   put word 1 of the hilitedline of me
end mouseup
```

Comment: The problem you mention here is solved in my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Edited with the additional info:

Is it really important to get the line)? You could try:

```
put returnNum("Diarrhea",gArrSymptoms)

function returnNum tItem, list
 repeat for each line L in list
  put L into tempL
  delete word 1 of tempL
  set the wholeMatches to true
  if lineOffset(tItem, tempL) >0 then return word 1 of L
 end repeat
end returnNum
```

Also, colors is a reserved word in LiveCode, so I used tColors here.

Comment: Hi bbglazer, I copies the color example from http://revolution.byu.edu/textfind/TextandFind.php My actual case is a list of food poisoning symptoms in an array separated by tab & return called gArrSymptoms. 2 Abdominal cramps
11 Abdominal pain
7 Bloody Diarrhea
16 Confusion
8 Cramps
5 Diarrhea
9 Facial pallor
6 Fever
13 Headache
12 Jaundice
3 Nausea
14 Stiff neck
10 Tea-colored urine
4 Vomiting
1 Watery diarrhea
15 Weakness

I tried you code with `put word wordOffset("Diarrhea",gArrSymptoms)-1 of gArrSymptoms into SymptomID and I get weakness instead of 5

Comment: I edited my response. You can try this function, but you cannot have white space at the end of each line since that will screw it up.

Comment: Hi bbglazer, I like the idea of using function as I have to find ID for a few items the same way.White space should not be a problem as I am selecting the item from a listbox.

Comment: I ended up using Marks code in a function but your works too

Answer (score 0):

LineOffset searches through multiple lines, but in your example, you only have one line.  Normally, you could use wordOffset within a single line, but you have an added challenge because one of your color names uses multiple words. So you could treat all words as items and use the itemOffset function instead:

```
put "1 blue 2 pink 3 reddish orange 4 orange 5 green 6 red 7 black 8 yellow" into theList
set the itemDel to space
set the wholeMatches to true
put itemOffset("reddish orange",theList) - 1 into N
put item N of theList into theColorID
```

Comment: Scott, my list actually have multiple lines and the items in each line is separated by tab

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a field with the following data:

```
2 Abdominal cramps
11 Abdominal pain
7 Bloody Diarrhea
16 Confusion
8 Cramps
5 Diarrhea
9 Facial pallor
6 Fever
13 Headache
12 Jaundice
3 Nausea
14 Stiff neck
10 Tea-colored urine
4 Vomiting
1 Watery diarrhea
15 Weakness
```

with line-delimited records and tab-delimited items in each record. You can use the following syntax to retrieve the ID number of any of the symptoms in the list:

```
put word 1 of line (lineoffset(tab & "Headache"& cr,fld 1 & cr)) of fld 1
```

Comment: Mark I like this short and sweet code but it fails with the last line. It can't find the ID for weakness. The array is generated through `put revDataFromQuery(tab,return,gDatabaseID,"SELECT * FROM tblSymptoms ORDER BY fldSymptoms") into gArrSymptoms'. Then I tried getting the ID through `put word 1 of line (lineoffset(tab & "weakness" & cr,gArrSymptoms)) of gArrSymptoms

Comment: I found a work around put word 1 of line (lineoffset(tab & "weakness" & cr,gArrSymptoms & cr)) of gArrSymptoms. works like a charm